# How to propagate time using linear inequalities?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, linearization

I have an adjacency matrix $G_{i,j}$ that tells the distance between $i$ to $j$ (between 0 to 1) if there is no edge between $i$ to $j$ I am putting a large integer $100$.

[This is my previous question related to it.](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/bounding-arrival-time-at-a-node-in-a-ressource-constrained-shortest-path-problem)

I am trying to linearize the following equation:

$s$ is the starting point, $e$ is the ending point.

$$\text{time}_j = \sum_i b_{i,j}\times \text{time}_i + G_{i, j} $$

My linearization is:

\begin{align}\text{time}_s&= 3.0\\\text{time}_j&\geq\text{time}_i + G_{i, j} - M \times(1 - b_{i, j})\\\text{time}_j&\leq\text{time}_i + G_{i, j}\\\text{time}_j&\geq 0\\\text{time}_j&\leq M \times b_{i, j}\end{align}

Value of $M$ is also $100$. Solver can't find the solution for this. If I remove the last 3 equations from linearization it finds the solution but for some node value of $\text{time}_j$ reaches to limit value $M$.

After the answer of @prubin:
\begin{align}
\text{time}_s&= 3.0\\
\text{time}_j&\geq\text{time}_i + G_{i, j} - M \times(1 - b_{i, j})\\
\text{time}_j&\leq\text{time}_i + G_{i, j} + M \times(1 - b_{i, j})\\
\text{time}_j&\geq 0\\
\end{align}

The value of $time_j$ is depending on  $time_i$ and $b_{i,j}$ I can only decide whether value of $time_j$ is $0$ or dependent on $time_i$ when I have seen value of all $i$ in $b_{i,j}$ i.e, $time_j$ = 0  if $\sum _i b_{i,j} = 0$ otherwise it is $time_j = time_i + G_{i, j}$ if $\sum_i b_{i,j} = 1$ now the important thing to note here is that same $i$ should be used in $time_i$ for which $b_{i,j} = 1$

Now with the above two equations, I iterate through all values of $i$ and if it is $b_{i,j} = 0$ range of $time_j$ is $[-M, +M]$ whenever I find the $b_{i,j} = 1$ value of $time_j =  time_i + G_{i, j}$ which is correct.

The problem is that when I don't find any $i$ for which $b_{i,j} = 1$ i.e., $\sum_i b_{i,j} = 0$ in that case the value range of $time_j$ is still $[-M, +M]$ but due to third equation it becomes $[0, +M]$.

My question is how that can be brought to the range $[0,0]$ if $\sum_i b_{i,j} = 0$

Update:

\begin{align}
\text{time}_s&= 3.0\\
\text{time}_j&\geq\text{time}_i + G_{i, j} - M \times(1 - b_{i, j})\\
\text{time}_j&\leq\text{time}_i + G_{i, j} + M \times(1 - b_{i, j})\\
\text{time}_j&\geq 0\\
\text{time}_j&\leq M \times \sum_i b_{i,j}\\
\end{align}

Comment: The problem that I have noticed so far is that the value of $\text{time}_j$  goes to the limit value M only for the last node i.e., $e$.

Comment: I modified my objective function and added the last node $\text{time}_e$ to it, now I am getting the proper results but processing time is increased, but my question is still that why the above relaxation not working.

Comment: I can't find how to bound $\text{time}_e$ so that it does not move to limit value.

Comment: For further reference of others, it would be helpful if you found a more "descriptive" title of your question: what is it that you actually want to ask?

Comment: OK, I will update the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constraint $\mathrm{time}_j \le \mathrm{time}_i + G_{i,j}$ is incorrect. It bounds $\mathrm{time}_j$ regardless of whether node $j$ follows node $i$ or not. Add the same "big M" term that you subtracted in the previous constraint.

Comment: But how can I use equals to zero case, as I am generating these conditions through loops for $i$ and $j$.

Comment: What do you mean by "equals to zero case"?

Comment: I have added a detail explanation in the question above. basically I am talking about the case when $\sum_i b_{i,j} = 0$

Comment: I have added linearization according to me at the end as an update , can you verify it.

Comment: It looks okay to me.